# Mocking InputStreamReader with console input in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I have the following code:

```
class MyWorker implements Runnable {
    MyReader reader
    Writer writer // java.io.Writer
    CommandFactory commandFactory

    @Inject
    MyWorker(MyReader reader, Writer writer, CommandFactory commandFactory) {
        super()
        this.reader = reader
        this.writer = writer
        this.commandFactory = commandFactory
    }

    @Override
    void run() {
        try {
            String line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Commands have an execute method.
                commandFactory.createCommand(line).execute(writer)
                writer.flush()
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            log.warn("${this} interrupted with: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex)}")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a Spock `Specification` that verifies several things happen when a newline (Enter Key) is pressed:

1. A `command` is executed
2. A `Writer` is `flush()`ed

Here's what I have so far:

```
class MyWorkerSpec extends Specification {
    def "when enter key is pressed then a command is selected and executed and the writer is flushed"() {
        given: "a running fixture with some mock dependencies"
        MyReader reader = Mock()
        Writer writer = Mock()
        Command command = Mock()
        CommandFactory commandFactory = Mock()
        commandFactory.createCommand(Spock.ANY) << command      // FIXME #1: Have it always return mock cmd

        MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(reader, writer, commandSelector)
        worker.run()

        when: "the enter key is pressed"
        // reader.input gives you a java.io.InputStream
        reader.input.write << '\n'                              // FIXME #2: Send it a newline

        then: "a command is executed"
        1 * command.execute(Spock.ANY)                          // FIXME #4: How to specify "any"

        and: "a writer is flushed"
        1 * writer.flush()                                      // FIXME #5 (how to guarante ordering of cmd -> flush)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm having a tough time wiring up the mock `CommandFactory` to return the mock `Command` given "any" input. I'm also having a tough time explicitly sending the mock `reader`'s `InpuStream` a newline (so as to trigger the scenario). I'm also not sure if the test method enforces ordering (first execute the command, *then* flush the `writer`).

Any ideas as to where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `>>` operator instead of `<<`. Moreover, any, in Spock, is the _ character.

To create a mock which always return a command, use :

```
def commandFactory = Mock(CommandFactory) {
  createCommand(_) >> command
}
```

Your MyReader should be mocked to return another mocked InputStream :

```
def readerStream = Mock(InputStream) {
  write() >> '\n'
}
def myReader = Mock(MyReader) {
  input >> readerStream
}
```

Finally, to order interactions, you should use multiple 'then' block :

```
then: "a command is executed"
  1 * command.execute(_)

then: "a writer is flushed"
  1 * writer.flush()
```